# How to use two Sonar's

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using a single sonar, but I want to use two sonar to know another distance.

Here is how I use my single sonar:

```
    #include <NewPing.h>

    #define TRIGGER_PIN  9
    #define ECHO_PIN  10
    #define MAX_DISTANCE  100 // in CM
    ...
    NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); 
    ...
    delay(100); 
    unsigned int uS = sonar.ping(); 
    int cm = uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
```

But I Want to use a second one to calculate another distance, how to?

```
#define TRIGGER_PIN_2  11
#define ECHO_PIN_2  12
...
new NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN_2, ECHO_PIN_2, MAX_DISTANCE);
...
???
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Maybe this one, I'll try this when I will get my second sonar

```
#define SONAR_NUM     2
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
...
NewPing sonar[SONAR_NUM] = {     
  NewPing(9, 10, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(11, 12, MAX_DISTANCE)
};
...
delay(100); 
unsigned int uS1 = sonar[0].ping(); 
int cm1 = uS1 / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM; 

unsigned int uS2 = sonar[1].ping(); 
int cm2 = uS2 / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
```

Comment: Who's sonar device are you using? Can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: @Duncan: I used this kind of untrasonic sonar http://www.hitronics.net/image/cache/data/Arduino/Ultrasonic%20Module/F90JYNWH7UR7RCS.LARGE[1]-500x500.jpg, and And I found Library here: https://code.google.com/p/arduino-new-ping/, http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you send a link to a source of the module rather than just a picture of it?

Comment: @Duncan : source is here: https://code.google.com/p/arduino-new-ping/downloads/list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe this one, I'll try this when I will get my second sonar

*Ding ding ding!* Yeah, this would be one way to do that. That creates an *array* so you can reference the sonar with `sonar[i]`, where `i` is either 0 or 1 for the first or second number.

For only two sensors, it might be easier just to do something like this:

```
NewPing sonar1(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);
NewPing sonar2(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);
```

Then you can run the other code like this:

```
delay(100); 
unsigned int uS1 = sonar1.ping(); 
int cm1 = uS1 / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM; 

unsigned int uS2 = sonar2.ping(); 
int cm2 = uS2 / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
```

A little less code to read, whichever one you want.

The reason you can do this is you can replace the `sonar` with whatever you wanted (following C++ variable rules like no spaces, etc.). You could call it `Arduino_Sonar` if you wanted to.

The array is basically a simple way of grouping variables together easily. It's not convenient to declare 500 differently name variables; I can just do `int numbers[500];` to declare them. An array might be more useful if you're expanding your circuit, but either is correct.

Comment: @Annonomous : Thanks, What a great price! I prefer your version, only two sonar's :-) Thanks for the support!